# PyBluez ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, bluetooth, importerror, pybluez

Whenever I Attempt To Import The bluetooth Module I Get This Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/super/PycharmProjects/untitled1/Sql.py", line 1, in   <module>
import bluetooth
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bluetooth\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
from .msbt import *
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bluetooth\msbt.py", line 2, in <module>
import bluetooth._msbt as bt
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Does Anybody Know How I Can Fix This

Comment: hey did you get this fixed? I have the same error!!

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading and installing the 64-bit "PyBluez-0.22-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl" from [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Installation:
pip install \complete_path\PyBluez-0.22-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl

This worked for me.